# How do I buy backlinks for a website project

Tags: php, html, wordpress-theming

Hi everyone hope you are fine. I am building a new website with wordpress for my client but he told me that I can buy for it backlinks such that it can rank well on search engines. I really want to buy them but I do not know where to buy backlinks. Help me guys. I did not intend to ask nonsense but I honestly need your help

Comment: We don't do recommendations, off-site links, commercial stuff etc., sorry. https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic. https://stackoverflow.com/tour, https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

Anyone offering such service is lying and it will not help at all for your search results. Your best bet is to promote your website on social media yourself.

That being said, here is a link that talks about such a service and weighs its pros and cons: [Backlinks: Do They Work And Are They Safe?](https://sirlinksalot.co/fiverr-backlinks/)

However, I would like to bring your attention to the part of the page where it says this:

```
The negative side to backlinks

 - They may penalize your website by clearly violating Google Webmaster
   Guidelines
 - They may diminish the quality of your website’s link profile, causing your site to get an increased spam score and slowing down it’s progress over time
 - May seem overwhelming
 - Fake reviews and fraud are rampant
 - Hard to truly know what you’re getting
 - The best sellers may be too expensive
```

Comment: Thank you so much.  I really appreciate your reply